# Open multiple txt files in python3

Tags: python, readfile

I have multiple txt files with similar names as follow: 
item1.txt, 
item2.txt, 
item3.txt,

item700.txt 
what is the best way to read these files' data in using python? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range) function to iterate over the 700 integers:

```
import os
import io

work_dir = "path/to/workdir"

for index in range(1, 701):
    name = "item{index}.txt".format(index=index)
    path = os.path.join(work_dir, name)
    with io.open(path, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as fd:
        content = fd.read()
```

A different way is to use [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) function to search for the text files:

```
for path in glob.glob(os.path.join(work_dir, "item*.txt")):
    with io.open(path, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as fd:
        content = fd.read()
```

Answer (score 1):

> Assuming all and only the text-files are in a Folder

```
import os 

all_txt_files = os.listdir(file_dir)

for txt in all_txt_files:
    txt_dir = file_dir + txt    
    with open(txt_dir, 'r') as txt_file:

    # read from a single Textfile whatever you want to
```

**Note:** Depending on your python version the Textfiles might not be sorted by `os.listdir()` prevent that by `sorted(os.listdir())`